# Adding <span> to alternating comma delimited list in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm receiving a comma delimited list of items from a database and placing them in a table cell, and I'd like to add alternating styles, so they are easily differentiated from one another.

ie,

foo, **bar**, mon, **key**, base, **ball**

such that the code looks something like this:

`<td class="wide">foo, <span class="alt">bar</span>, mon, <span class="alt">key</span>, base, <span class="alt">ball</span></td>`

So, I'd like to add a span class to the alternate values.

Is there an easy way to do that in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're ambiguous as we don't know if you start with the `<span>` elements being present or if you only have the comma separated list as plain text, and the `<span>` elements are added by jQuery.

### If you have the `<span>` elements before the jQuery

Using jQuery, you could use the [`:even` selector](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/).

```
$('td.wide span:even").addClass("alt");
```

### If you don't have the `<span>` elements before the jQuery

(untested)

```
var list = $('td.wide').html();
var listAsArray = list.split(',');
var newListHtml = '';
for(var i=0; i<listAsArray.length; i++) {
    if(i%2==0) {
        newListHtml += '<span class="alt">';
    }
    newListHtml += listAsArray[i];
    if(i%2==0) {
        newListHtml += '</span>';
    }
}
$('td.wide').html(newListHtml);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't start with anything but the comma delimited list, without any semantic markup.

Answer (score 2):

I would make the list into a `ul`, and then use the `:nth-child` selector to style each even `li`.

No, it wont work in every browser, but it is a far neater way than using `span` tags and javascript, and seeing as it is merely a minor visual aide (no meaning will be lost if the style is not displayed) it is less critical for it to work in older browsers.

For more info on `:nth-child`, see:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo
http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd

Comment: +1 for `<ul>`, and if I could there'd be another for `:nth-child`.

Comment: +1 and if the css `:nth-child` does not have sufficient browser support, you can always fall back on the jquery one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting it from the database, you probably want to do this on the server side, and add those elements in your HTML; not with jQuery.

However, why use `<span>` elements? The keyword in your title and your question I've seen is *list* - yet there is no use of (my *favorite* HTML elements!) `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

What server-side language are you using? I'll assume PHP... when you read the comma separated list out of the DB, turn it into a list, and then use CSS to add commas. You can do that with a `background-image` of a comma, or with a CSS [pseudo-element](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_elements.asp) and the [`content`](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_gen_content.asp) property.

### Example

In a PHP server-side script:

```
<?php
    $readFromTheDB = "foo, bar, mon, key, base, ball";
    $list = $keywordsArray = array_map('trim', explode(',', $readFromTheDB));
    echo "<ul>";
    $oddEven = true;
    foreach($list as $listitem) {
        $class = ($oddEven?"odd":"even");
        echo "<li class=\"".htmlentities($class)."\">".htmlentities($listitem)."</li>";
        $oddEven = !$oddEven;
    }
    echo "<ul>";
?>
```

Then in your CSS file:

```
ul li {
    background:url(path/to/images/comma.png) BOTTOM RIGHT NO-REPEAT;
    display:inline;
}
ul li.even {
    font-weight:bolder;
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Probably semantically preferable, but seems like a bit of heavy lifting for a simple problem. 

Also, it doesn't seem like $oddEven does anything besides stay at 1?

Comment: ... but the underlying idea to add the elements and the class server-side isn't heavy; I think it's a much better solution than using JavaScript to do it.

Comment: I agree, using Javascript for this is probably making things a lot hard than they need to be.  It makes so much more sense to do this on the server side, rather than using Javascript to modify the HTML afterwards.

Comment: @Kibee - Thanks! I appreciate the validation - I was wondering if my opinion was ass backwards ever since I got that commentless -1 :P

Answer (score 1):

```
function spanize(commaDelimitedString){
   var items = commaDelimitedString.split(',');
   var result = [];
   $.each(items, function(i){
       if(i%2 != 0)
           result.push('<span class="alt">' + this + '</span>');
       else
           result.push(this);
   });
   return result.join(',');
}
```

Nothing awesome, but works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var data='foo, bar, mon, key, base, ball';

    // Add SPANs to all text parts
    $('#insertdata').html('<span>'+data.split(", ").join("</span>, <span>")+'</span>');

    // Add the highlighting to the odd spans
    $('#insertdata span:odd').addClass('alt');

    // Remove SPANs that are not needed
    $('#insertdata span:even').each(function() {
      $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
    });
  });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
  .alt {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr><td id="insertdata"></td></tr>
</table>
```